# Actionscript 3.0 Navigation working on Home Page Only?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am using the following code for my Navigation in a FLash CS4 file:

```
stop ();
function buttons(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(event.target.name);
}
home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttons);
services.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttons);
about.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttons);
contact.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttons);
```

It works great when I am on the home page, but stops working once I navigate to any of the other pages. I have an Actions layer and that layer extends the full length of all pages/frames of the timeline.

I have the frames labeled as such: home, services, about, and contact. (All are "Type:Name")

each button is named as such: home/ instance of "home", services/instance of "services", etc.

Comment: Does your button layer extend to the full length of all pages/frames?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you button have instance names all the way down the timeline. Every place where the layer that holds your buttons has a keyframe check the buttons and make sure they still have the same instance names.